# WebSeal authentication how to get started

Tags: webseal

I am working on implementing WebSeal single sign-on so that the user does not have to enter credentials for a particular web application if the user is already logged in via Windows authentication. Can anyone please point me in the right direction. I am new to Web Seal

Answer (score 2):

WebSEAL has something called junctions. You can create webseal junctions and configure it to application webservers. Suppose if your SSO solution involves 3 applications, three webseal junctions has to be created. Webseal will act as reverse proxy in this case. So when a user trying to access anyone of the application, He will be challenged with a login screen from webseal. User will be authenticated against LDAP(u need to map your ldap in webseal) and his session will be maintained at webseal.Once authenticated user information will be sent to application servers via junction in HTTP headers. Now when user access other two application, he will not be challenged with authentication. His information will be sent to application servers directly via headers as webseal maintains his session.

For more info:
https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/tividd/td/ITAME/SC32-1359-00/en_US/HTML/am51_webseal_guide16.htm

Answer (score 0):

WebSEAL supports Windows single sign on using SPNEGO protocol & Kerberos Authentication. Read this link for configuration steps:-

https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/tividd/td/ITAME/SC32-1359-00/en_US/HTML/am51_webseal_guide78.htm#sso-windows-desktop